Index not properly updating in a multifile document using standalone/import
I'm working on a large text, using multiple .tex files. I use the standalone / import packages to merge them into one single pdf document. At this time there are roughly 10 different .tex files included, each of them including entries to the index. All .tex files have the same preamble (which is kinda long, so I probably can't post the entire preamble here). For some of my .tex files the index of my big pdf file is updating just fine, however, for others it doesn't. I've already deleted the .idx file but that didn't help. This is kinda weird. If was because of a faulty preamble the index shouldn't be working at all, so I'm puzzled. There are no spacebars or special characters in the name of the included .tex files, so it can't be because of that.
I think the following excerpt from my preamble contains all the important lines regarding this issue:
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside, openright]{book}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeindex
\makeindex[name=symbols, title=Symbols]

\begin{document}
...
\end{document}

The main tex. file I then looks something like this (using the same preamble):
\begin{document}
\chapter{Preface}

\subimport{1_First_Part}{1_First_Part}
\subimport{2_Linear_Algebra}{2_Linear_Algebra}
\subimport{3_Real_Analysis}{3_Real_Analysis}


\printindex{symbols}
\printindex

\end{document}

Now, if, for example, in the second .tex file I add \index{matrix} and \index[symbols]{$\sup$}, while in the third file I add \index{integral}. I can't see any reason why the first and second of those entries would be included in my indexes but not the third one. Anyone got an idea what could cause such an issue?

Don't guess whether the code is enough: test it. If you compile the code you've given us can you reproduce the issue? If it isn't possible to compile the code you've provided as is, it isn't complete. We can't diagnose a problem (usually) without seeing the cause. Does the log say anything? Are the entries correctly written to the .idx file? Are parts of both indices written?

Sorry, I there was an issue with  \begin{thebibliogrphy}[99] ... \end{thebibliography}, I've removed it from the sample code, was unnecessary to add it in the first place anyways. If I run that sample code it works just fine, two different indexes are created and updated each time I add an entry.

However, I cannot reproduce the issue with the above code since it works flawlessly.

So the problem is solved? We don't have the files you're importing, but if you solved the problem we could just close this.
